# SassError undefined variable vanilla js date picker compilation in datepicker-bulma.scss

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, sass

am trying to implement date picker in angular application using vanilla js am getting compilation error in $white variable SassError undefined variable  in datepicker-bulma.scss  and cjs.js .
Can anybody suggest here

```
$dp-background-color: $white !default
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was unable to import their sass, but I was able to import their compiled CSS instead and that worked:

```
@import 'node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/dist/css/datepicker';
@import 'node_modules/vanillajs-datepicker/dist/css/datepicker-bulma';
```